# Syntastic is not working for c++

Tags: vim, syntastic

I recently installed Syntastic via pathogen according to this guide https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic#installpathogen.

However, Syntastic is not working for c++. It does however work for c. 
I am not sure what the reason is, when I open .cpp files and intentionally create an error, nothing gets reported.

Here is my vimrc:

```
:syntax on
:set number
:set autoindent
:set cindent

set t_Co=256 "sets vim to 256 color
if &term =~ '256color'
" disable Background Color Erase (BCE) so that color schemes
" render properly when inside 256-color tmux and GNU screen.
    set t_ut=
endif

"Synastic
let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler = 'clang++'
let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options = ' -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++'
let g:syntastic_cpp_check_header = 1

nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR> "maps f8 to tagbar toggle

execute pathogen#infect()

:colorscheme mustang
```

Answer (score 11):

This has probably been answered elsewhere as well. Did you try to debug Syntastic?

Try setting `let g:syntastic_debug=1` into your .vimrc., run the checker, and check the output of `:mes` to debug any issues
Alternatively, you could type `:SyntasticInfo`, which will output something like the following:

```
Syntastic version: 3.4.0-134
Info for filetype: cpp
Mode: active
Filetype cpp is active
Available checkers: clang_check clang_tidy gcc
Currently enabled checkers: -
```

You can thus enable the proper checkers you desire by adding them to your .vimrc: `let g:syntastic_cpp_checkers = ['clang_check', 'gcc']`, or you can specify your own rules. For doing so, you can check the manual by typing `:h syntastic`.